# Adblocker disabled CKEditor 4 textarea so one cannot write into it

Tags: ckeditor4.x

Adblocker disabled CKEditor 4  textarea, so user cannot write text into it.

please view the problem in video
https://adnan_ranksol.tinytake.com/sf/MzAyODM3OF85MDc4MzA2

Answer (score 0):

The only solution for this is you have to detect ad blocker and then show the pop-up so that user aware of this, the user then deactivated the ad blocker and can the editor there is no any handling of this with CK editor yet 
by this script

```
/ detect adBlocker /
    var adBlockEnabled = false;
    var testAd = document.createElement('div');
    testAd.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
    testAd.className = 'adsbox';
    document.body.appendChild(testAd);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        if (testAd.offsetHeight === 0) {
            adBlockEnabled = true;
        }
        testAd.remove();
        console.log('AdBlock Enabled? ', adBlockEnabled)
    }, 100);
```